# Does sourcetree provide any tool or screen for editing gitignore file?

Tags: gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

Recently I put some extension to global gitignore file by sourcetree.

But I found out it was wrong decision.

So I want to change it.

But I do not know which .gitignore file the sourcetree uses for saveing global ignore list. (I have so many .gitignore file in my computer)

So, I want to know sourcetree provide any good tool or screen for edit global gitignore file list.

I found some articles for doing by command line, but it is kind of hard to do it for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[image]If you are using latest source tree (v2.5.3), Locate the setting icon which is at top right corner of app window. Then Select advance tab and click on edit button which opens it via text edit app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following steps fixed the problem for me on my Windows 7 box:

1) Open regedit.exe

2) Search for "gitignore_auto_file"

3) Replace the program parameter in the registry setting with your desired edit tool, using the exact path and program name, make sure to enclosed this in quotes as illustrated below:

```
 a) e.g.: "C:\MyFolder\MyUniqueEditor.exe" "%1"
```

4) When SourceTree executes the GUI, and looks up this entry in the Windows registry, then

```
      1) the "%1" is the parameter that is past to your choosen editor
```

It is acknowledged that it would be helpful if SourceTree provided the functionality to undo/re-do the edit tool selection, if a mistake is made.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like sourcetree does not provide gui window for managing gitignore list.

but you can edit it simply.

Just go to home folder of you.
Usually the folder is icon with house. (in mac system)
Then you can found .gitignore_global file. That's it.
You can edit a file with text edit tool like textedit, atom and so on.

[image]

---

[update]

We can simply edit about it in sourcefree 'Preferences' 
And there is 'Edit File' button.

[image]